# Ask an uint, get an int

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, int, uint

I know the use of anonym function have to be done with parsimony but :

```
private function getAnonymFct() : Function
{
    return function () : void
    {
        var num : uint = -1;

        if( num < uint.MIN_VALUE )
            trace( "WTF ??" );
        trace( getQualifiedClassName( num ) );
        trace( num );
    }
}

public function Main()
{
    getAnonymFct()();
}
```

Will trace :

```
int
WTF ??
-1
```

Any ideas why my var num magically become an int instead of uint as typed ?

Answer (score 1):

Type `uint` is shorthand for unsigned integer, `-1` is not a valid unsigned integer, it is a signed integer and is less than `uint.MIN_VALUE`. I would assume, to avoid an obvious runtime error actionscript has converted num to type `int`.

In AS both unsigned and signed are stored as 32-bits and `-1` in base10 as `int` would be `11111111111111111111111111111111` in base2, converting that to `uint` it would be `4294967295` in base 10, which is `uint.MAX_VALUE` and 10 orders of magnitude different to the original number